# Postgres - XMLQuery / XQuery

Tags: xml, postgresql

How can I use xmlquery in postgres?

ex:
This is in SQL Server Xml Query

```
SELECT MyXmlField.query('data(/root/product[@id="304"]/name)') FROM MyTable
```

I cannot find any documentation related to XmlQuery function in postgres.

Comment: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-xml.html

Comment: i have seen this page, nothing related to xmlQuery is presented

Answer (score 0):

Then you have to look closer:

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-xml.html#FUNCTIONS-XML-PROCESSING

See XPath section.

Comment: no xquery in postgres , xpath have differant syntax